# jQuery ,each inside another .each

Tags: jquery

Okay, I know why this doesn't work, I just don't know how to fix it.

I have a section of a form that can be cloned. What I want to do is get each of those sections as a separate thing.

```
  $('.product-row-form').each(function() {
    var quote = ''
    $('.control').each(function() {
      quote += $(this).data('field') + ': ' + $(this).val() + '<br>'
    })
    console.log(quote)
  })
```

Obviously this will return one 'quote" with all the .controls on the page together. What I need to do is have that inner .each run only on the .control elements inside the specific .product-row-form for each iteration of that .each

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can I have the .product-row-form and .control html ?

Comment: so reference the one that you are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the [second argument](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) of `$`:

```
$('.control', this)
```

Comment: I can't believe I tried this but got the arguments reversed >.< Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.product-row-form').each(function() {
    var quote = ''
    $(this).find('.control').each(function() {
      quote += $(this).data('field') + ': ' + $(this).val() + '<br>'
    })
    console.log(quote)
  })
```